# urlsession, how would you get the overall progress on multiple files download

Tags: ios, swift, download, progress, urlsession

Using a URLSessionDownloadTask. Is there any way to get the overall progress of a multiple files download using the delegate didwritedata?  in a

I have the expected size of all files, now I need the totalbyteswritten  for all current tasks and then all future tasks would be added to this "pool"..right now by default the totalbyteswritten are by task.

Using the task identifier maybe?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but the answer is to create a [`Progress`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/progress/) for each download. When you create them, add them as children to a parent `Progress`, and that will then rollup the data from the children, updating the parent `Progress`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using a `URLSessionDownloadTask`. You should add that to your question.

If you have multiple download tasks running you should save them to a collection of some sort. A dictionary would work well. You will need to sum the total bytes written for each task into a total yourself.

Comment: that's the idea, but how can you separate one task from another? I mean let's say I have 2 downloads running in parallel , so 2 tasks with their own bytes received and their own progress, how can I do something like this: overall bytes received = task 1 totalbyteswritten + task 2 totalbyteswritten. Thx!

Comment: As you create each download task, save it in an array. Create a struct with info about a download including total bytes written. Save those structs to a dictionary with the download task as the key. As the delegate message is called with totalBytes info, fetch the struct using the download task as the key and  update the structure.